# Hand Detection using C#

Tags: c#, opencv, unity-game-engine

I am working on a project in **Unity-Android** that requires Gesture Recognition properly and efficiently (as it will be running in a mobile) for further processes.

Currently, I am using HSV to detect the hand region which is not that accurate even when a touch-input is taken from the user.

Please refer to me a solution that is efficiently detecting hand region. It should be robust as the user will be opening/closing any number of fingers or rotating the hand.

Note:
As I'm working on **Unity**, I need help in **C#** only

Comment: have you tried OpnenCV?

Comment: Yes @SaadAnees, could be more specific? I have tried lots of things of openCV like SVM (feature detection algorithms), cascade models, HSV

Comment: As far as i know you cant get 100% accuracy with mobile camera. You need to use some special camera like 3D camera such as Realsense 3d or Leap Motion.

Comment: I understand that but as far as my current (HSV method) is concerned there has to be a better way than this and that's what I'm looking for